# How to calculate $E[E[Y|X]\mathbb{1}_A]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ take values from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $p_{ij} = P(X=i, Y=j)$. Let $A= \{ Y$ is odd $\}$. How to calculate $E[E[Y|X]\mathbb{1}_A]$?

\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/4 & 1/4\\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3\\
1/4 & 1/2 & 1/4
\end{bmatrix}

I think $E[Y\mathbb{1}_A] = \sum_{a\in A} aP(Y=a)$, but I do not think it is true that $E[E[Y|X]\mathbb{1}_A] = \sum_{a\in A} aP(E[Y|X]=a)$ because $E[Y|X=1] = 7/4, E[Y|X=2] = 2, E[Y|X=3]=2$ while $a = 1$ or $a=3$.

$E[Y|X]$ does not equal $1$ or $3$, so $E[E[Y|X]\mathbb{1}_A] = 0$?

Comment: Why do you not think it is true?

Comment: @user6247850 I have updated my post with my reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

> but I do not think it is true that $E[E[Y|X]1_A]=∑_{a∈A}aP(E[Y|X]=a)$ because

Of course not.
$A$ is the event that "$Y$ is odd".  It is *not* the event that $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)$ is odd.

---

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X)\,\mathbf 1_A)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X)\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_A\mid X))\\[1ex]&=\sum_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}} \mathsf P(X=i)~\mathsf E(Y\mid X=i)~\mathsf P(Y\in\{1,3\}\mid X=i)\end{align}$$